# Change log level for Apache Jackrabbit under Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, logging, jackrabbit

I am attempting to view INFO- or DEBUG-level log messages for Apache Jackrabbit 2.7.X running under Tomcat 7. I've searched for awhile and found two different possibilities on how to do this:

- Add a WEB-INF/log4j.xml file with the appropriate configuration
- Set Java-level properties, e.g. `log4j.logger.org.apache.jackrabbit`

This seems like a simple task but thus far I've not been able to make either of the above work for me.

I am particularly interested in seeing some of the "internals", e.g. what data is received over the wire versus what is created in the repository, and so forth. I don't even know if this is possible but I figure logging everything is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 10 minutes after posting this I found the answer, so here it is in case somebody is trying to do the same and finds this at a later date.

Although the documentation says:

> Are there any notable log entries? Check the log files for any related
>   warnings or errors. By default the Jackrabbit JCR Server writes log
>   entries to the standard output of the servlet container. You can
>   customize logging by editing the /WEB-INF/log4j.xml file and
>   redeploying this web application.

This appears to be incorrect as in fact the newer Jackrabbit uses logback, and the configuration file in the standard distribution is:

```
 WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml
```

In which you can change the basic level and append to the console as such:

```
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  </root>
```

You can get more advanced from there, it appears. Make the change, restart the container, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

On jackrabbit 2.10.1, you should put this in **WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %-40([%thread] %F:%L) %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```